# How can I display a custom list of templates in Navigator?

Tags: daml

The [Navigator tool](https://docs.daml.com/tools/navigator/index.html#) comes with the ability to display custom tables, defined through the [frontend-config.js](https://docs.daml.com/tools/navigator/index.html#customizable-table-views) file. The [quickstart example](https://docs.daml.com/getting-started/quickstart.html) contains such a file that defines a custom list of contracts.

Is it also possible to display a custom list of templates?

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom list of templates, add a custom view with `source.type=="templates"`.

Here is an example of a custom view that would list all tempaltes that have "Iou:Iou" in their template ID:

```
  iouTemplates: {
    type: "table-view",
    title: "Iou Templates",
    source: {
      type: "templates",
      filter: [
        {
          field: "id",
          value: "Iou:Iou",
        }
      ],
      search: "",
      sort: [
        {
          field: "id",
          direction: "ASCENDING"
        }
      ]
    },
    columns: [
      {
        key: "id",
        title: "Template ID",
        createCell: ({rowData}) => ({
          type: "text",
          value: rowData.id
        }),
        sortable: true,
        width: 80,
        weight: 0,
        alignment: "left"
      }
    ]
  }
```